# Map table names of a database with values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mapping

I have some table names in `test` database in MySQL. I have a table called `mapping` in database `renamed` that has information of tables that have been renamed.

Now I want to have a list of the tables that are in `test` database and their renamed name in the `mapping` table.

Tables in `test`

```
123_abc
124_abc
235_test
```

Information in `mapping` table

```
table       renamed

123_abc     123_abc_test
235_test    235_testing
abc_test    abc_test1
```

Now I want a list that contains table names that are in `test` database and their renamed names in the `mapping` table in `renamed` database

The expected result is

```
123_abc     123_abc_test
235_test    235_testing
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the information_schema database that's part of MySQL and which contains all of MySQL's meta-information (including table names) like this:

```
select t1.TABLE_NAME, t2.table_name 
from information_schema.`TABLES` t1 
where table_schema = 'test' 
inner join renamed.mapping t2 on 
    t1.table_name = t2.table_name
```

Granted, with an inner join, you'll only get the tables that are actually renamed. If you want all the tables in your test schema, do a left join instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can issue a MySQL statement like,

`select * from renamed.mapping inner join information_schema.tables on renamed.mapping.table_name = information_schema.tables.TABLE_NAME where information_schema.tables.TABLE_SCHEMA='test'`